# xslt transformation of a xml based on the value in a node variable incremental xml

Tags: xslt, foreach, substring, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i have a java based application entering data into a table with columns by name  fieldName and its fieldValue am trying to re group for another use
in an array format i have tried using for-each to get the substring after the customer and before : but its not working that way
INPUT:

```
<Data>
      <fieldName>customer0:fname</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>fremont</fieldValue>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <fieldName>customer0:mname<</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>u</fieldValue>
   </Data>
   <Data> 
      <fieldName>customer0:Lname<</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>usa</fieldValue>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <fieldName>customer1:fname</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>Hyd</fieldValue>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <fieldName>customer1:mname<</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>M</fieldValue>
   </Data>
   <Data> 
      <fieldName>customer1:Lname<</fieldName>
      <fieldValue>india</fieldValue>
   </Data>
```

```
OUTPUT:
I am trying to convert this into below format
```

```
  <responsexml>
    <ResponseList>
      <firstname>fremont</firstname>
      <middlename>u</middlename>
      <lastname>usa</lastname>
    </ResponseList>
    <ResponseList>
      <firstname>hyd</firstname>
      <middlename>M</middlename>
      <lastname>india</lastname>
    </ResponseList>
  </responsexml>
```

Comment: What have you tried (post your code)? What doesn't work? This seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSL applied to the following XML works.
First I do a grouping on the customer (key function). I am considering that everything that comes before ":" is the customer number.

After, for each instance inside the grouping, I test the fieldName to check if it is the first, last or middle name (all options) and then I add the value to the right node.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:key name="Customer" match="Data" use="substring-before(fieldName, ':')" />


    <xsl:template match="root">
        <responsexml>
            <xsl:for-each select="Data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Customer', substring-before(fieldName, ':'))[1])]">
                <ResponseList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('Customer', substring-before(fieldName, ':'))">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="substring-after(fieldName, ':') = 'fname'">
                                <firstname>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="fieldValue"/>
                                </firstname>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="substring-after(fieldName, ':') = 'mname'">
                                <middlename>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="fieldValue"/>
                                </middlename>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="substring-after(fieldName, ':') = 'Lname'">
                                <lastname>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="fieldValue"/>
                                </lastname>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ResponseList>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </responsexml>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <Data>
        <fieldName>customer0:fname</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>fremont</fieldValue>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <fieldName>customer0:mname</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>u</fieldValue>
    </Data>
    <Data> 
        <fieldName>customer0:Lname</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>usa</fieldValue>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <fieldName>customer1:fname</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>Hyd</fieldValue>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <fieldName>customer1:mname</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>M</fieldValue>
    </Data>
    <Data> 
        <fieldName>customer1:Lname</fieldName>
        <fieldValue>india</fieldValue>
    </Data>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you that saved time for me.